# Stuck on a proof for a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $λ_1, \ldots , λ_n$ and that $S$ is an invertible matrix. Suppose that each column of $S$ is a multiple of a standard basis vector (i.e. an  $e_i$). Prove that $S^{−1}DS$ is diagonal.

A diagonal matrix is a matrix in which the entries outside the main diagonal are all zero.
two $n$-by-$n$ matrices $S$ and $D$ are called similar if $D = S^{-1} D S$.

I have no idea what to do from here on. Am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if there exists a matrix $X$ such that $A = XBX^{-1}$

Comment: Try working out some 3 by 3 examples, just choose random $S$ and $D$ that meets your requirement.

Comment: See first what is $DS$. Is it very different from $S$? Maybe start with $2\times 2$ example.